# Select radio item in edit view Django Template

Tags: python, django

I am making an edit view and I would like to have some radio fields selected when fetching the results.
My issue is that I can't make my values of the forloop and the values from database comparing correctly. Let me be more clear with some code. I have these lists named mission_entry and gradings. mission_entry has some grades inside it, a vote from 1 to 5 in each value of the list.

views.py

```
    mission_entry = MissionEntry.objects.filter(log_entry_id=log_entry_id)
    gradings = range(1,6)
```

models.py

```
 GRADING_VALUE = (
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '2'),
    ('3', '3'),
    ('4', '4'),
    ('5', '5'),
)
    class MissionEntry(models.Model):
        student = models.ForeignKey(
            Student, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
        mission = models.ForeignKey(
            Mission, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
        log_entry = models.ForeignKey(
            LogEntry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
        learning_objective = models.ForeignKey(
            LearningObjective, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
        grade = models.CharField(
            max_length=10, choices=GRADING_VALUE, blank=True, null=True)
        comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

template

```
 {% for lo in mission_entry %}
      <tr>
        <td id='learning_obj'>{{lo.learning_objective.name}}</td>
        {% for grade in gradings %}
          <td>
            <input class="form-check {{grade}}" {% if lo.grade == grade %}selected{% endif %} type="radio" value="{{grade}}" name="grade{{lo.learning_objective.name}}" id="grade" required/>
          </td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="note" id='note' value="{{lo.comment}}"></td>
      </tr> 
      {% endfor %}
```

I know that {% if lo.grade == grade %}selected{% endif %} is the wrong piece of code. Basically I am comparing in the template a string with an integer, but I can't understand how to manipulate my variables to compare them. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, you're comparing strings to integers, which is why it doesn't work. You could change `gradings` to be strings instead of integers:

```
gradings = list(map(str, range(1, 6)))
```

Note, also, that both `map` and `range` return a generator - which means you'll only be able to iterate over it once in your template. To fix this, you need to first convert it to a list.

Where [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) converts every item in the iterable to a [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

Alternatively, you could change your `grade` field to an `IntegerField` instead of a `CharField`. This would be more appropriate if you only intend to store integer values, and would be better suited to things like ordering items by `grade` in future.

Comment: For some weird reason, if I change gradings with the map feature, the loop works just for one line and not all the lines in the loop. 
I’d rather maintain a charfield because I could also have letters instead of numbers in the grading field.

Comment: What do you mean by "it works for one line"? By definition the `if` statement will only be true for one line in the loop. You probably also don't want to set `required` on every option because you can only select one radio element at a time.

Comment: With "working with one line" I mean that I have multiple lines in the loop of mission_entry. But if I convert the gradings in the map function it works only in the first line of the mission_entry forloop and not in the other lines.

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain why that was happening - you need to convert the generator to a list before you pass it to the template. Otherwise you can only iterate over it once.